# Ubuntu 16.04LTS freezing after login, desktop frozen, mouse moves but cannot click

Tags: kernel, login, freeze

Ubuntu 16.04LTS freezing after login, desktop frozen, mouse moves but cannot click. This happens after the computer has been asleep for awhile left unattended as it's primarily just a server.

I've seen other reports of this issue.

Any solutions? I also checked and I believe I have the latest kernel version, so I'm stumped..